# Compute the list, and it's sublists in reversed order Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, reverse, sublist

I have a list formed of integer numbers and lists of integer numbers, and I want to compute the lists in reversed order (each sublist is reversed)

```
%addToEnd(E:number,L:list,LR:list)
%addToEnd flow model(i,i,o)
addToEnd(E,[],[E]).
addToEnd(E,[H|T],[H|TR]):-
    addToEnd(E,T,TR).
%reverse(L:list,LR:list)
%reverse flow model(i,o)
reverse([],[]).
reverse([H|T],L):-
    reverse(T,LR),
    addToEnd(H,LR,L).
```

How do I compute the sublists in reversed order?

Answer (score 0):

```
reverse([H|T],A,R):-
    number(H),
    reverse(T,[H|A],R).

reverse([H|T],A,R):-
    is_list(H),
    reverse(H,[],X),
    reverse(T,[X|A],R).

reverse([],A,A).
```

This is the working version I have found.